# I need a conversion function, from integer to date-time

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, utc, datetime-conversion

Is there a conversion to go from an integer (ex:  54600) to date-time format?  I am seeing the integers in a flowsheet in healthcare, used to record a time

CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, b22.meas_value * 1000, 0), 114) AS 'START TIME' :  Is the code that worked in MS SQL, but SNOWFLAKE does not recognize the function.

Comment: Which date and time does for example 54600 signify?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html). The data type of the returned value is DATE.

Syntax

```
TO_DATE( '<integer>' )
```

where

```
<integer>
An expression that evaluates to a string containing an integer, for example ‘15000000’. Depending upon the magnitude of the string, it can be interpreted as seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds.
```

For details or other usage, see the above link.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways:

```
select 1637804567::varchar::date as date;
+------------+
| DATE       |
|------------|
| 2021-11-25 |
+------------+

select to_date(1637804567::varchar) as date;
+------------+
| DATE       |
|------------|
| 2021-11-25 |
+------------+
```

TO_DATE or CASTING will require the value to be string, so you need to convert the integer to string first before converting to date.

For your example, it will be like below in Snowflake:

```
select dateadd(ms, 54600*1000, to_date(1637804567::varchar)) as date;
+-------------------------------+
| DATE                          |
|-------------------------------|
| 2021-11-25 15:10:00.000000000 |
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

[TRY_TO_TIME()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_time.html) (there's a joke in there somewhere)

```
 select try_to_time('54600') AS "START TIME"
```

[image]